# getting arraylist from BulletedList control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a BulletedList control in my project. I want to assign BulletedList control's all items to an array variable.

There are 3 items in BulletedList.

```
string[] array = new string[3];

array = blistselected.Items.Value;
```

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate through the Items Collection using for or foreach like this.

```
string listCount = blistselected.Items.Count;
string[] array = new string[listCount];
for (int i=0; i<blistselected.Items.Count; i++) 
{
    array[i] = blistselected.Items[i].Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the [ListItemCollection.CopyTo() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.copyto.aspx).

So it would be:

```
string[] array = new string[3];
blistselected.Items.CopyTo(array, 0);
```

I've purely done this through looking at the docs, so may need changes and type conversions etc.

Also as there are 3 items your array has an extra element.

Comment: Thx Edmondson. I got error: At least one element in the source array could not be cast down to the destination array type.

Comment: Yea you'll likely have to call `.toString()` or cast it.